# Can i use sharepoint server 2007 with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2007

Can i use sharepoint server 2007 with Visual Studio 2010?, Is there any issue about it to pay attention to?

Comment: Yes you can use it. You need to specify exactly what you are looking to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can. And you can use [WSPBuilder](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wspbuilder) also.

## Issue with Workflows

There is an issue with Workflows however. If you create SharePoint workflow, you cannot add SharePoint workflow items from toolbox, they are greyed out.

A workaround is to manually add required element by editing .designer file and then you have that element in the Designer with which you can afterwards interact normally.

[image: SharePoint toolbox greyed out]